# Binary Variable Measurement Error in Diff-in-Diffs

Tags: bootstrap, difference-in-difference, measurement-error

I have a Difference in Differences (DiD) model with a special kind of measurement error. The true $2\times2$ DiD model is given by:

$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 T_i + \beta_1 P_t + \delta P_t \times T_i + x^*_{it} + \varepsilon_{it}
$$

where $i = 1, 2, \dots , n$ is the index for individuals in my sample and $t = 1, 2, \dots, T$ the time index. $T_i$ is a dummy equal to $1$ for the treatment group and $P_t$ a dummy equal to one for the periods after the treatment was administered. $x^*_{it}$ is a control variable for which I have measurement error.

This measurement error is due to a false assigment: every individual $i$ is assigned a workplace, and for this workplace I observe a time trend $x_t$ (note that different individuals can have the same workplace). Now, for the control group $(T_i = 0)$, all workplaces are assigned correctly. For the treatment group, workplaces are assigned by a partly random heuristic which produces incorrect assignments. E.g. individual 3 might be assigned to workplace A instead of B, and this individuals time trend $x_{it}$ is then the wrong one. Hence I do not observe the true trend $x^*_{it}$, but a trend and an error $e_{it}$:
$$
x_{it} = x^*_{it} + e_{it} \qquad e_{it} = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } T_i = 0 \\
 x_{it} - x^*_{it}  &\text{if } T_i = 1
 \end{cases} \quad \Rightarrow e_{it} \text{ is correlated with } T_i
$$
So my actual model is given by:
$$
y_{it} = \beta_0 T_i + \beta_1 P_t + \delta P_t \times T_i + x_{it} + (\varepsilon_{it} - e_{it} )
$$
Since the error $e_{it}$ is correlated with $T_i$, I have an endogeneity problem (Classical Measurement Error that leads to an attenuation bias).

### My Questions

1. Does the measurement error only affect $T_i$ or also the other variables?
2. Would bootstrapping solve the problem? I.e. assigning the workplaces using the heuristic, estimating the parameters 1000 times and taking the average of the resulting parameters.

   - I have simulated such a bootstrap and found that while $\beta_0$ was indeed underestimated, all other parameters had their true values. My intuition is that the bootstrap "removes the average assignment error"